# How to install wingide

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, wing-ide, kali-linux

I'm trying to install wingide on a Kali Linux virtual Machine. I have downloaded the ide directly from the website, then put this code into the terminal:

```
dpkg -i wingide6_6.1.4-1_amd64.deb
```

After loading, it says exactly this:

```
dependency problems prevent configuration of wingide6:
wingide6 depends on libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.18.0); however:
package libpango1.0-0 is not installed
(LEAVING OUT SOME CODE)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wingide6
```

I assume I have to install the "libpango" software, but I don't know how to do that. Also, I don't know what it means by the last line, "error encountered".

When I try to run

```
apt-get -f install
```

It asks me if I want to delete the wingide. Shouldn't it try to install the libpango? I am very confused.

### Edit

Also, when I try

```
sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-0
```

it doesn't work. It says something along the lines of "the package could be missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source"

Comment: It's fine for anyone to email support@wingware.com for help w/ this product.  The high-level description for Stack Overflow is "Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers" and I think people don't understand how that's being defined so will (not entirely unreasonably) ask about things like installing a particular IDE.  Would be nice if some day questions just self-organize into the right Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why it thinks Wing uses libpango... it doesn't.  I think you can work around this like this:

dpkg --force-all -i wingide6_6.1.4-1_amd64.deb

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to have worked somewhat, but I am still confused. Once i ran that, the last two lines that it sent back were "Setting up wingide6 (6.1.4-1) ...          Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47+b1) ..." and then it stopped. If that seems correct to you, where can I open up wingide?

Comment: It should have added Wing to the Development menu, or start it with wing6.1 on the command line.